# split an hot observable to multiple observable

Tags: stream, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I want to split an hot observable into multiple observable like follows

```
source: 'a' - 'b' - 'c' - 'd' - 'e' - 'a' - 'b' - 'c' - 'd' - 'd' - 'd - 'x' - '$' - 'z'......

output(array of observable):
  'a' --------------------------'a'----------------......
  ----- 'b' -------------------------'b'-----------......
  ------------'c' ------------------------'c'------......
  ----------------- 'd' ---------------------'d'-'d'.....
  -------------------------'e'---------------------......
```

groupBy doesn't work with hot observable.
partition only split an observable into 2 observables

I can make custom operator which use filter operator internally like partition operator. but it looks inefficient for my example because I have to apply filter operator many times to source.

Comment: Why `groupBy` wouldn't work with hot Observables?

Comment: Just because "it looks inefficient" doesn't mean it's inefficient.

Comment: @martin groupBy waits until the observable completes.

Comment: @cartant ok, I have to split 1 observable into more than 1000 observables.

Comment: If your `groupBy` implementation does not behave as you'd expect it to, you should share it, instead.

Comment: @cartant ....it is the way groupBy works. It works as I expect and doesn't fit in this casse. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bqukwn

Comment: `groupBy` doesn't wait for observable to complete what is waiting is `toArray` - in your example. Could you maybe share a little bit of code...

Comment: @m1ch4ls Thanks! https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bqukwn

Comment: @cartant and martin. My apology. I was confused.

Comment: @monad98 I am confused a little bit... Were you able to achieve what you wanted? You example looks the same but without `toArray`...

Comment: @m1ch4ls yes. I was able to split hot observable into several observables (in this case, by age). Thanks.